# Count numbers of checkboxes and update MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm updating some MySQL data for specific entries selected through checkboxes, my code for that looks like this:

```
<?php
    if($_POST['code_approve']){
        for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['checkbox']);$i++){
            $approval_id = $checkbox[$i];
            $sql = "UPDATE table SET status='approved', used='processed' WHERE id='$approval_id'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
        }
        if($result){
            echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=table.php\">";
        }
    }
?>
```

Now I want to know how many checkboxes have been selected, and for every checkbox selected add 25 to table "members" row "balance".

I tried like this:

```
<?php
    if($_POST['code_approve']){
        for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['checkbox']);$i++){
            $approval_id = $checkbox[$i];
            $approvedamount = count($_POST['checkbox'])
            $approvedx25 = $approvedamount * 25;
            $sql = "UPDATE table SET status='approved', used='processed' WHERE id='$approval_id'";
            $sql2 = "UPDATE members SET balance = + '$approvedx25'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
        }
        if($result){
            echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=table.php\">";
        }
    }
?>
```

But that didn't work at all, what's the proper way to do this ?

//EDIT

Please ignore this question, it worked, i just forgot to add the mysql_query.

Comment: I think that you should remove the quotes in teh where clause and make it like that, for start: WHERE id=$approval_id.. also where is that checkbox array come from?!?$checkbox[$i].. I think too much of your code is missing

Comment: You should not run SQL queries in a loop, it is not very efficient. Collect the IDs in the loop, then write one UPDATE query using IN.

Comment: Look at 'Check box group' section here: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html

Answer (score 0):

Your update query should be something like this:

```
$sql2 = "UPDATE members SET balance = balance + ".$approvedx25;
```

The way you wrote it, the update in withing the `for` clause, thus executed once for every checkbox. I'm not sure you want that, since you already multiply by the number of checkboxes.

Also, mind, your second query (`$sql2`) is not executed in your code.